# IOS : passing data between viewController (destination embedded in a NavigationController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, model-view-controller, storyboard

I'm just learning IOS development, I would like to pass data between ViewController. I'm using Storyboard and I'm using the "prepareForSegue" method.

My main question is about the pattern I found in many forums and blogs about this "transmission" of information. When the origin controller needs to pass data to a destination controller, the origin controller access the destination controller using the code :

```
[segue destinationViewController]
```

This is fine, the origin controller doesn't need to know exactly the destination controller details (I'm using protocols).

But when the destination controller is a NavigationController (a ViewController embedded in a NavigationController), it seems that the recommended practice is :

```
[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController]
```

But if I do that, it means that the origin controller must know that the destination controller IS a NavigationController. I would like to avoid that if possible ?

Maybe I'm doing something wrong ? Is there another way to do it ?

The origin controller is a "detail page" (coming from a TableView), the destination controller is the "edit page".

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

1. Use `-isKindOfClass` and check if it's a `UINavigationController`
2. Create a protocol whith a `-rootViewController` method, create two categories conforming the protocol, one on `UIViewController`, another on `UINavigationController`, implement both, the one for `UIViewController` should return `self`, the one for `UINavigationController` should return `topViewController`. Now you'll be able to drop those categories on any controller, and use `[[segue destinationViewController] rootViewController]`

Comment: I selected this answer because the use of Categories which I didn't know (I'm learning). Categories seems to solve my issue in a very clean way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem with #2 above is that UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController, and [defining methods with the same name in two different categories can lead to problems](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4). Specifically, you can't be certain which implementation of `-rootViewController` UINavigationController will use.

Comment: In fact, I checked before selecting this answer, and the issue you mention occurs only if my Category method would have the same name as a class method. I will be sure that UINavigationController will use the category defined for this class as overriding works the same way for category methods. So the method in my category for UINavigationController will override the method in my category for UIViewController. If I understood correctly "category" is just a way to organize code, so usual inheritance rules apply. Again, I'm learning (I'm a java dev) so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
UINavigationController *navTmp = segue.destinationViewController;

YourController * xx = ((YourController *)[navTmp topViewController]);
xx.param = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the `destinationViewController` is a `UINavigationController`, and if it is, then get its `topViewController`. That way it just automatically handles either case, and it's safe.

Comment: I may do that if it's the only way. I would like to hope there is another alternative. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It seems like a reasonable thing to do. It could be very thorough even and check to see if the view controller is one of the other container types and get a child from it. Then when it finds one that's not a container view controller, it could check to see that it conforms to the protocol you're using.

Answer (score 0):

> But if I do that, it means that the origin controller must know that
>   the destination controller IS a NavigationController. I would like to
>   avoid that if possible ?

One possible solution is to subclass `UINavigationController` such that it can accept whatever data your source controller provides and in turn passes that data on to its root view controller. That might make particular sense if you have a number of segues, some leading to nav controllers and some not, and you want to handle them all the same way.

In other words, create a `UINavigationController` subclass that acts like a proxy for its root controller.

Comment: Thanks for this proposition. It is simple but the solution of @emanuelpenaaguilar with categories is more appealing to me.